# Google Apps Free mail Notifier?

Tags: email, google-workspace

I’m looking for a free mail notifier for Google Apps mail. Gmail notifier does not work and Chrome notifier doesn’t have sound notifications—that is the main feature I need.

The one I found is [GmailNotifier](http://gmailnotifier.net/files/), but it’s not free. Anyone knows a free one?

Comment: They are giving it for “free” if you can give them a link to their site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of Chrome extensions that do a nice job, although they don't help much if you don't always keep Chrome open.

This one is great, although it uses quite a bit of memory: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/oeopbcgkkoapgobdbedcemjljbihmemj

Comment: is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

X-Notifier is free, works with Google Apps including multiple accounts and plays a sound from a URL.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apebebenniibdlpbookhgelaghfnaonp